# Preventing race condition and probably incorrect access token expiration time check

Tags: c#, .net, race-condition

Anytime I call SendAsync, it should automatically authenticate the API if the access token has expired.

The issue is that `_accessTokenExpirationTime` may lead to a race condition. How do I protect against it, SemaphoreSlim?

I also don't think the way I did it, is correct. I mean it works, but `DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds` is probably wrong because what if the response delays with 1 minute and the access token's lifetime remains the same?

Any suggestions are welcome.

```cs
public sealed partial class Client : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _clientId;
    private readonly string _clientSecret;
    private readonly ILogger<Client> _logger;
    private readonly WebSocketClient _client;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, TaskCompletionSource<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>>> _outstandingRequests = new();
    
    private DateTime _accessTokenExpirationTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public Client(string clientId, string clientSecret, ILoggerFactory? loggerFactory = default)
    {
        _logger = (loggerFactory ?? NullLoggerFactory.Instance).CreateLogger<Client>();
        _clientId = clientId;
        _clientSecret = clientSecret;

        _client = new WebSocketClient("wss://www.deribit.com/ws/api/v2", loggerFactory);

        _client.Connected += OnConnected;
        _client.Disconnected += OnDisconnected;
        _client.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _client.Connected -= OnConnected;
        _client.Disconnected -= OnDisconnected;
        _client.MessageReceived -= OnMessageReceived;

        _client.Dispose();
    }

    public Task StartAsync()
    {
        return _client.StartAsync();
    }

    public Task StopAsync()
    {
        return _client.StopAsync();
    }

    private async ValueTask EnsureAuthenticated()
    {
        // TODO: Prevent race condition?
        if ((_accessTokenExpirationTime - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalSeconds < 30)
        {
            var response = await AuthAsync(_clientId, _clientSecret).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response is { Error: { } })
            {
                _logger.LogError("Error requesting authentication token: {Message}", response.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (response is { Result: { } })
            {
                _accessTokenExpirationTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(response.Result.ExpiresIn);

                _logger.LogInformation("Authentication token received. Expires in {ExpiresIn} seconds.", response.Result.ExpiresIn);
            }
        }
    }

    private async ValueTask<TResponse> SendAsync<TResponse>(string method, object @params, bool isPublic)
    {
        if (isPublic)
        {
            await EnsureAuthenticated().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        var request = new JsonRpcRequest("2.0", Guid.NewGuid(), method, @params);
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        _outstandingRequests.TryAdd(request.Id, tcs);
        return await SendRequestAndWaitForResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        async ValueTask<TResponse> SendRequestAndWaitForResponseAsync()
        {
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

            await _client.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, Task.Delay(5000)).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (completedTask != tcs.Task)
            {
                tcs.SetException(new TimeoutException("The operation timed out"));
                _outstandingRequests.TryRemove(request.Id, out _);
            }

            var response = await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TResponse>(response.Span) ?? throw new JsonException("Could not deserialize the object");
        }
    }

    public ValueTask<JsonRpcResponse<AuthInfo>> AuthAsync(string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var @params = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "client_id", clientId },
            { "client_secret", clientSecret }
        };

        return SendAsync<JsonRpcResponse<AuthInfo>>("/public/auth", @params, false);
    }

    private void OnConnected(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _accessTokenExpirationTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    private void OnDisconnected(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void OnNotification(Notification notification)
    {
        var callbacks = _subscriptionManager.GetCallbacks(notification.Params.Channel);

        foreach (var callback in callbacks)
        {
            try
            {
                Task.Run(() => callback(notification));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "OnNotification: Error during event callback call");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnMessageReceived(object? sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using var document = JsonDocument.Parse(e.Message.Buffer);

            if (document.RootElement.TryGetProperty("method", out var methodElement))
            {
                // Handle request
                var method = methodElement.GetString();

                Debug.Assert(method != null);

                if (method == "subscription")
                {
                    var notification = document.RootElement.Deserialize<Notification>();

                    Debug.Assert(notification != null);

                    OnNotification(notification);
                }
                else if (method == "heartbeat")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Heartbeat");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("Unknown server request");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle response
                var response = document.RootElement.Deserialize<JsonRpcResponse<object>>();

                Debug.Assert(response != null);

                if (!_outstandingRequests.TryRemove(response.Id, out var tcs))
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("Could not find request id {Id}", response.Id);
                    return;
                }

                if (response.Error != null)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(new JsonRpcException(response));
                }
                else
                {
                    tcs.TrySetResult(e.Message.Buffer);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error handling message response: {ExceptionMessage}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public record AuthInfo(
    [property: JsonPropertyName("access_token")] string AccessToken,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("expires_in")] int ExpiresIn,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("refresh_token")] string RefreshToken,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("scope")] string Scope,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("state")] string? State,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("token_type")] string TokenType);

public record JsonRpcResponse<T>(
    [property: JsonPropertyName("jsonrpc")] string JsonRpc,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("id")] Guid Id,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("result")] T? Result,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("error")] JsonRpcError? Error,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("testnet")] bool Testnet,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("usIn")] [property: JsonConverter(typeof(MicrosecondEpochDateTimeConverter))] DateTime UsIn,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("usOut")] [property: JsonConverter(typeof(MicrosecondEpochDateTimeConverter))] DateTime UsOut,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("usDiff")] long UsDiff)
    where T : class;
```

Comment: Couldn't you sidestep this by just letting it fail if the token has expired and then retry with a new one?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean to be looking for an invalid_credentials error message or whatever message their API was giving for unauthenticated state and when it does that, to authenticate and repeat the SendAsync call? Similar to how Authorization is done in angular2+ using HTTP interceptors?

Comment: Yes, exactly - API calls can fail for all sorts of reasons, so retrying a few times before really failing is a common strategy.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That's a great idea!